# Modal content update with ajax actions without close it after user actions - Odoo frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, odoo-11

In my project i have a modal windows that manage attachments for selected line as you can see in the photo below:

[image]

The problem is that with modal window every actions, such as attachment remove or attachment add close the modal.

I'm trying to find a way to update the container with list of attachments after every user action without close the modal until the user don't press "Close" or "X".

Here is the jQuery (with some Odoo custom call):

```
function remove_selected_attachment(post) {
    ajax.jsonRpc("/my/sale_worksheet_line/remove/attachment", "call", post)
        .then(function (data) {
            if (data === "raise_error") {
                //FIXME: check that case or manage it
                 window.location.href = "/my/sale_worksheet/" + $("input[name='sale_worksheet_id']").val();
            } else {
                $('.container').load(window.location + " .container>*", "");
            }
        });
}

// onClick bind that manage attachment removes
$(document).on("click", ".js-delete-current-attachment", function (ev) {
    let $button = $(this);
    let attachment_id = $button.val();
    let worksheet_line_id = $button.siblings('input[name=worksheet_line_id]').val();
    let post;

    post = {
        'attachment_id' : Number(attachment_id),
        'worksheet_line_id': Number(worksheet_line_id),
    };
    //ev.preventDefault();
    remove_selected_attachment(post);
});
```

The ajax.jsonRpc() just call my controller that delete the attachment and return a response.

Here is the Javascript widget that show modal template:

```
odoo.define('sale_worksheet.attachment_form.instance', function (require) {
'use strict';

    require('web_editor.ready');
    var WorksheetAttachmentsWidget = require('sale_worksheet.website_sale_worksheet_widgets');

    var $form = $('.attachment_new_form');
    if (!$form.length) {
        return null;
    }

    var instance = new WorksheetAttachmentsWidget();
    return instance.appendTo($form).then(function () {
        return instance;
    });
});

//==============================================================================

odoo.define('sale_worksheet.website_sale_worksheet_widgets', function (require) {

    require('web.dom_ready');

    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var Widget = require('web.Widget');

    var _t = core._t;

    var WorksheetAttachmentsWidget = Widget.extend({
        start: function () {
            var self = this;
            var res = this._super.apply(this.arguments).then(function () {
                $('.attachment-button')
                    .off('click')
                    .click(function (ev) {
                        self.on_click(ev);
                    });
            });
            return res;
        },
        on_click: function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            //Get the button class list because contain the id of related form
            var buttonClassList = $(ev.currentTarget).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
            var $form = $('#' + buttonClassList[0]);
            var $button = $(ev.currentTarget).closest('.attachment-button');
            var post = {};
            $button.attr('disabled', true);

            return ajax.jsonRpc($form.attr('action'), 'call', post).then(function (modal) {
                var $modal = $(modal);
                $modal.modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
                $modal.insertAfter($form).modal();
                $modal.on('click', '.js_goto_sale_worksheet', function () {
                    $modal.modal('hide');
                    $button.prop('disabled', false);
                });
                $modal.on('click', '.close', function () {
                    $button.prop('disabled', false);
                });
            });

        },
    });

    return WorksheetAttachmentsWidget;
});
```

And the rendered Template:

```
<!-- Modal Template for Sale Worksheet lines attachment details-->
<template id="attachments_line_details" name="Sale Worksheet's Attachment Details">
    <div id="modal_attachment_details" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <form id="attendee_registration" t-attf-action="/my/sale_worksheet/#{slug(worksheet_line)}/attachment/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="js_website_submit_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="worksheet_line" t-att-value="worksheet_line"/>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><strong>Worksheet Line Attachment</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                                <input type="file" name="input_attachment" class="o_website_form_input form-control" accept="image/*,application/pdf"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left mt8" value="Load"/>
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
                            <h5>Loaded Attachments:</h5>
                            <t t-foreach="worksheet_line.attachment_ids" t-as="attachment">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 worksheet_line">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <span t-field="attachment.name"/>
                                        <a t-attf-href="/my/sale_worksheet_line/get/attachment/#{slug(attachment)}" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right">
                                            <i class="fa fa-download"/>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="worksheet_line_id" t-att-value="worksheet_line.id"/>
                                        <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger pull-right js-delete-current-attachment" t-att-value="attachment.id">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"/>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </t>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger js_goto_sale_worksheet" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

It's possible to achieve what i need with a modal windows?
Or i must manage it with an hidden div inside the DOM and just call `toggle()` only when users click "Close" or "X"??

Comment: Are you saying that when you click the 'Load', 'Delete' or 'Download' buttons, that the modal closes?

Comment: Just the "Load" and "Delete".
But the load it's normal because the <form> post submit redirect to the path with all details (i need to manage an ajax file submit)...

The problem is the "Delete" because into .then() method of ajax when the response come back the modal disappear.
I try with ev.preventDefault() and the screen background still black but the modal disappear.

I would like update attachments rows only when user delete one attachment